# How to catch the value from ajax id in php?

Tags: java, php, ajax

I Call in my php page this script.: `<script type="text/javascript" src="getData.js"></script>`
It gets all data from my selected item from my dropdown box.

In that script the data wil be loaded from a PHP page that get values from mysqli and set it to a jsonencode data.
The data from the json encode will be placed in my ajax code with this `$("#emp_RColorbMax").text(employeeData.RColorbMax);
$("#emp_RColora").text(employeeData.RColora);`

This data i then can see with this for example.: `<div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_RColorbMax"></div>`

So what i choose in my select box , all data changes with it and also will be loaded.

Everything works like a charm, but, that data i also want to use to check if in one of my input fields has the right value.
So what i mean , if i fill in my input field 17 and emp_RColorbMax is lower then that the input field must be colored.

I tried to do this.:

```
if (isNaN(get_value) || get_value <?php echo '<div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_RColorbMin"></div>' ?> || get_value <?php echo '<div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_RColorbMax"></div>' ?>) {

    $('#KleurL').css({'backgroundColor':'red'});
}  else { //$("#KleurL").addClass('green');
    $('#KleurL').css({'backgroundColor':'white'});
};
```

But that doesn't work, how do i must handle `<div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_RColorbMin"></div>`?

Comment: $('#KleurL').css({'backgroundColor':'red'}); should be $('#KleurL').css('backgroundColor', 'red');

Comment: Oke, i will try that, but the with the : also works. Nobody that an solve the issue how i can handle id to use that in my code?